# Will creation of the full memory dump in process explorer slow down a windows service, whose memory I'm trying to dump?

Tags: windows-services, windbg, memory-dump, process-explorer

Or same memory dump creating in Windows Task Manager. It is also interesting how exactly these programs  create memory dumps..thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to ask Mark Russinovich.  Stepping into his considerably oversized shoes, I'd certainly suspend every thread before making the dump.  The underlying winapi call is MiniDumpWriteDump().

Comment: Procdump has the -r option to "Reflect (clone) the process for the dump to minimize the time the process is suspended (Windows 7 and higher only)."